# How can I hide the "View All" link in a related object list view?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, related-list, list-view

I have multiple "related object" list views on a lightning object page. Each list contains a "View All" link underneath it. This link is unnecessary and confusing because the list already contains all the objects that the user needs to see in this context. How can I remove that link?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Related List OOTB component shows 4 records by default and throws in a 'View All' button to view others on demand. Unfortunately, there is no 'setting' to hide that link at this time. If you absolutely need to hide it, I am afraid you must resort to implementing a custom component from scratch. On a side note, please consider upvoting this idea: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Br1rAAC